# Can anova be tested without any categorical variable?

Tags: regression

Can assumptions be lenient enough to

allow anova be tested even if exogenous varibles are not categorical?

Comment: What are you trying to find out about your data?

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA is the same model as linear regression.  When none of the exogenous variables is categorical, no one uses the term ANOVA.